# Validating json data for dynamic form

Tags: javascript

I have a array-object which should look something like this and is used to create a form

```
const questions = [
  {
    condition_action: "selected",
    label: "What is your name?",
    question_type: "free_text",
    required: true,
  },
  {
    condition_action: "selected",
    label: "Where do you live?",
    question_options: [
      {
        label: "India",
      },
      {
        label: "china",
      },
      {
        label: "japan",
      },
    ],
    question_type: "single_answer",
    required: false,
  },
];
```

Now, When user is done creating the form, I have to validate the data and add a key name `order` in the above snippet (more below) to array-object (main array and question_options)

For validation, There are two conditions

1. Main array-object should have a label (if not throw error).
2. Question option should have at-least 1 item and the label inside it can't be empty

Basically, question_options is for multiple-select and single select drop down. So question_option should only contain value if `question_type` key in the above snippet is `single_answer` or `multiple_answer`

The backend api also require attribute `order` on the main question array and question_options array (yeah even though it's an array we could determine the order through index)

So this is the code I wrote

```
   const validateAndFormatdata = (questions) => {
    // we will change this to true if error exist and send it at return of this function
    let errorsExsist = false
    // we are formating data here, if error exist while validation, we change flag
    const formatedData = (questions || []).map((question, index) => {
      // delete all previous errors since we are iterating and we don't care about our previous errors
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(question, "errors")) {
        delete question.errors
      }
      // There can be more than one thing wrong, hence using an array
      const newErrors = []
      // if label does not have value, add it it in errors array
      if (question.label === "") {
        newErrors.push(errorReasons.missingLabel)
      }
      if (
        question.question_type === "multiple_answer" ||
        question.question_type === "single_answer"
      ) {
        const questionOptions = _.filter(question.question_options, "label").map(
          (option, position) => {
            return {
              ...option,
              order: position
            }
          }
        )
        // if question optiond does not have single item, add it it in errors array
        if (questionOptions.length < 1) {
          newErrors.push(errorReasons.noOption)
        } else {
          question.question_options = [...questionOptions]
        }
      } else if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(question, "question_options")) {
        // remove question otpions of question type isn't single or mult-text
        delete question.question_options
      }

      if (newErrors.length > 0) {
        errorsExsist = true
        question.errors = newErrors
      }
      return { ...question, order: index }
    })
    return {
      errorsExsist,
      data: formatedData
    }
  }
```

**Question:** I was wondering if someone can share review, optimisation and suggestions (including naming)?

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes and added comments for each change.

```js
// add the default array here ------------↓ 
const validateAndFormatdata = (questions = []) => {
  let errorsExist = false, // <- typo in exist
      // in case you want to add new types
      optionTypes = new Set(["multiple_answer", "single_answer"]);
      
  // no need to check for || [] because default is added
  // remove the errors property here itself by using destructuring
  const formattedData = questions.map(({ errors, question_options, ...question }, index) => {
    // because of the destructuring, question is a new object.
    // So, will not mutate the original object
    question.order = index;

    const newErrors = []
    
    // checks if label exists and if it is an empty string
    if (!question.label) {
      newErrors.push(errorReasons.missingLabel)
    }
    
    if (optionTypes.has(question.question_type)) {
      const questionOptions = question_options
                                    .filter(q => q.label)
                                    .map((option, order) => ({ ...option, order }));
                                      
      // === 0 is much more clearer to read
      if (questionOptions.length === 0) {
        newErrors.push(errorReasons.noOption)
      } else {
        // no need for [...]. It's a new array
        question.question_options = questionOptions
      }
    }
    // no need for delete question.question_options because it is destructured

    if (newErrors.length > 0) {
      errorsExist = true
      question.errors = newErrors
    }

    return question;
  })
  
  return {
    errorsExist,
    data: formattedData
  }
}
```